# PHP Datetime Convert slash to minus

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to convert my datetime 08/11/2013 to 2013-08-11.

I was trying this, but it did not work as it suppose to.

```
$date = $_POST['gt_date']; // Getting 08/11/2013
$date = explode("/", $date); // Exploding the / character into array
$datetime = $date[2] + '-' + $date[0] + '-' + $date[1];
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: The answer has been given already, but to answer your question, the output was "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the + does, but changing your code to the following will work:

```
$datetime = $date[2].'-'.$date[0].'-'.$date[1];
```

Edit: I guess the + was adding them together. Was the result you were getting 2032?

Comment: Lol, indeed you're right! Thank you for correcting my mistake James!

Comment: Well I was used to the + in C#, but I like the fact that PHP made this easier :-). The result= "0000-00-00 00:00:00"

Answer (score 4):

You can pass it to `DateTime` to format it for you.

```
$date = new DateTime('08/11/2013');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Not if it's GMT format: DateTime('13/08/2013') will result in error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will return your format so that you don't have to repeat your code.

```
function makeDateFormat($date) {
    $date = $_POST['gt_date'];
    $date = explode("/",$date);
    $new_date = array($date[2], $date[0], $date[1]);
    $date = implode("-",$new_date);
    return $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the "+" operator, replace it with "." operator. You could use this function:

```
function formatDate($date) {
    $arr = explode("-",$date);

    $year  = $arr[2];
    $month = $arr[1];
    $day   = $arr[0];

    return $year."-".$month."-".$day;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice function but correction is this below if you want to covert format as well:

```
echo makeDateFormat('13/02/23','Y-m-d');

function makeDateFormat($date,$date_format) {
        $date = explode("/",$date);
        $new_date = array($date[2], $date[1], $date[0]);
        $date = implode("-",$new_date);
        $date=date($date_format,strtotime($date));
        return $date;
    }
```

Another way if your require to format date as per your requirement:

```
$date=explode("/","13/02/23");

$new_date_format=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[0]));
```